# Casting 8-bit int to 32-bit

Tags: c, endianness

I think I confused myself with endianness and bit-shifting, please help.

I have 4 8-bit ints which I want to convert to a 32-bit int. This is what I an doing:

```
uint h;
t_uint8 ff[4] = {1,2,3,4};

if (BIG_ENDIAN) {
    h = ((int)ff[0] << 24) | ((int)ff[1] << 16) | ((int)ff[2] << 8) | ((int)ff[3]);
}
else {
    h = ((int)ff[0] >> 24) | ((int)ff[1] >> 16) | ((int)ff[2] >> 8) | ((int)ff[3]);
}
```

However, this seems to produce a wrong result. With a little experimentation I realised that it should be other way round: in the case of big endian I am supposed to shift bits to the right, and otherwise to the left. However, I don't understand WHY.

This is how I understand it. Big endian means most significant byte first (first means leftmost, right? perhaps this where I am wrong). So, converting 8-bit int to 32-bit int would prepend 24 zeros to my existing 8 bits.  So, to make it a 1st byte I need to shift bits 24 to the left.

Please point out where I am wrong.

Comment: Well, what is `ff[0] >> 24`? Do that by hand and see result. Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe try to do it with union ?

Comment: You say you get a "wrong result". What result did you get, and how is that different from what you expected?

Comment: What is the order of the bytes in ff?  Do you know if ff[0] is supposed to be the most-significant byte, or the least-significant, or does it depend on the machine's endianness?  (In other words, how did the bytes in ff get set originally?)

Comment: @hyde bitshifting operation.

Comment: I meant, what result you get for that shift.

Comment: @KurtRevis The code shows how the bytes were set. t_uint8 is 1 byte in size.

Comment: So is ff[0] = 1 supposed to be the most significant byte, or the least significant byte?  They're just bytes, and can be interpreted in any order; it's entirely up to you and your code. Your machine's endianness doesn't affect whether you are interpreting ff[0] as the most significant or least significant byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have to shift the 8-bit-values left. But in the little-endian case, you have to change the order of indices, so that the fourth byte goes into the most-significant position, and the first byte into the least-significant.

```
if (BIG_ENDIAN) {
    h = ((int)ff[0] << 24) | ((int)ff[1] << 16) | ((int)ff[2] << 8) | ((int)ff[3]);
}
else {
    h = ((int)ff[3] << 24) | ((int)ff[2] << 16) | ((int)ff[1] << 8) | ((int)ff[0]);
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that when I cast 8-bit int to 32-bit int I always get additional 24 zeros ON THE LEFT, irrelevant from endianness?

Comment: Yes (but only for unsigned values, for signed values you might get 24 *ones* on the left if the value is negative). Endianness is about byte order, not bit order.

Comment: @IvanInTheHat When you cast 8 bit int to 32 bit int, the *value* does not change. So, if you look at it as binary number on paper, only place you can add zeros without changing value is indeed "ON THE LEFT". How it is stored in memory under some CPU architecture has no bearing on how it looks on paper or what value it must keep.

Comment: @hyde, thank you for another explanation, my mistake was in thinking that bit-shifting operates on the raw bits in the memory. I was pointed out that it is indeed not the case and bit shifting is performed on the mathematical value, so endianness doesn't matter in this case.